# Advice for beginner on making an app which has labels which content changes daily. Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, variables, storyboard

I can’t find anything particularly useful online so far. How can I make an app which has text which changes daily? Or can someone help me be pointed in the right direction of where to start.

Example would be a basic quote of the day app, the layout remains the same but the text of the labels varies

Comment: Good advice would be: Learn the language, learn the framework, write the app.

Comment: You might fetch these quotes from a server, which gives you the daily quote or you will need to store all that quotes in your local database / storage of the app and then load a new one every day depending on the data. However, the user might modify the app and change the date.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super-advanced with Swift and Xcode, but I have learned a lot in the past few months.

I would highly suggest you go on YouTube and watch any video about creating a simple app. I know they might be an hour long, but these videos are ultra helpful.

Those videos will provide a basic understanding of Xcode, Swift, and UI Building. It will make iOS development on Xcode easier.

**As far as your app idea**, I actually developed something extremely similar before. So, I know the struggles you might encounter.

What I would suggest you do is look into how you can use a database to store your quotes, and then how you can retrieve and display them on your screen.

I use Google Firebase for my database because it is very user-friendly and there are many resources out there on it.

Try checking that out. Good luck and don't get discouraged!

Comment: I do have a basic understanding of Xcode and swift and have done some basic apps before just never used an external data base or had changing content. I will look on YouTube though!!

Comment: Ooh okay. I apologize for taking you as a beginning beginner. I would definitely recommend Firebase then. There are a bunch of tutorials on writing to and retrieving data from a Firebase Database.